# remove top left back button

Tags: swift, watchos-4

I would like to remove the top left back button.

I tried to check "Full screen" option, but the arrow is still here.

I want to remove the back button because I have a button next to this button, and I don't want the user tap on it by mistake

Thx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2868441-reloadrootpagecontrollers) the deprecated method that was in the previous answer (which used to solve this issue) has been replaced with:

```
reloadRootPageControllers(withNames names: [String], 
                            contexts: [Any]?, 
                         orientation: WKPageOrientation, 
                           pageIndex: Int)
```

"**Parameters**

**names**

An array of NSString objects, each of which contains the identifier of an interface controller in your storyboard file. The order of the identifiers in the array defines the order of the corresponding interface controllers in the page-based interface.

**contexts**

An array of objects of type id. Use this parameter to pass context objects to each of the interface controllers loaded into the page-based interface. The first object in the array is passed to the first interface controller, the second object is passed to the second interface controller, and so on.

**orientation**

The scrolling orientation for the page-based interface. For a list of valid values, see WKPageOrientation."

And pageIndex should be pretty simple to figure out. If you only have one element in [names] it will be 0. Otherwise you should select the index of the page you want loaded from [names]

Comment: I need informations about WKPageOrientation parameter. `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'WKPageOrientation'`. Do you have an example about this it ?

Comment: If you read though the documentation, it’s an enumeration with two values .horizontal and .vertical. You could also use 0 or 1.

Comment: Im noob in swift, when I put a string I have an error: WKPageOrientation type expected

Comment: Don't use a string. It's like using `UIColor` you can set the value like `UIColor.black` and in most cases you can just use `.black` So for `WKPageOrientation` you could pass it as a parameter with `.horizontal` or `.vertical`. If that doesn't work then do the full call `WKPageOrientation.horizontal` NO QUOTES

Comment: [This is](https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/) a good explanation of swift enumerations.

Comment: I put it in the awake() function of my controller (where the back button has to be hidden), that works, but when I use a deep press I have the following error: `_puic_setViewControllers:animated: called on <PUICNavigationController 0x7a07c200> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.`

Comment: What functions should be triggered on your deep press? Can you ask another question outside of this thread, post the code there, and share the link for the new question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49373924/reloadrootpagecontrollers-and-deep-press

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllersWithNames(["myInterfaceController"], contexts: [])`

This removes it by making the controller the root controller. You may have to reload the controller after calling this.

Comment: I called it in the awake() function in my controller but I have the following error `Value of type 'MainController' has no member 'navigationItem'`. Where i'm suppose to call it ? Have I need to import something ? Thx

Comment: navigationItem seems to be only for ios and tvos

Comment: Updated the answer for IntetfaceController.

Comment: `reloadRootControllersWithNames` is depreciated for watchOS 2.0–4.0. Do you know what is `WKPageOrientation` expected parameter in `reloadRootPageControllersWithNames` ?

Comment: @Paul No clue. Sorry