# reloadRootPageControllers and deep press

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm using `reloadRootPageControllers()` to remove the top left back button.

```
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)

    // Configure interface objects here.
    WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["MainController"], contexts: [], orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)

}
```

That works, but when I use a deep press (to show 3 choices) I have the following error:

> _puic_setViewControllers:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

and the thread is freezed.

Comment: If you could edit this to show the code for the deep press and the functions that the press calls that would be beneficial

Comment: @jake, the error is displayed when the deep menu is open, not when I select a choice.

Comment: Okay. What makes the deep press work? What code allows for the deep press to call the menu? Did you do it in a storyboard file? Or is there code you wrote that gets called? I haven't written any WatchKit apps, but something gets called on that gesture. It will be tough to help without understanding what gets called.

Comment: I put a print() message just before the reloadRootPageControllers, the message is displayed continuously.

Comment: Okay, call an `if` statement. like `if self.window.rootViewController is MyViewController {
    //do something if it's an instance of that class
} else { reloadRootPageControllers } `

Comment: ok, I moved the reloadRootPageControllers just before my pushController calls. Seems to be fine now.

Comment: cool. ignore my other comment then

Comment: Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: No problem!! If you need anything in the future message me. I'm not an expert by any means but I learn a ton when someone needs help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the `reloadRootPageControllers` in the Controller.

Replace

```
pushController(withName: "MainController", context: nil)
```

By

```
WKInterfaceController.reloadRootPageControllers(withNames: ["MainController"], contexts: [], orientation: .horizontal, pageIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Do you need the `pushController` function when you've called `reloadRootPageControllers`?

Comment: No indeed... ;)